# how to make the countdown timer to count till zero?

Tags: android

here is the code im using...my countdown timer doesnt display 0(zero) after 1...how to do it...I have tried replacing 1000 with 0 in countdown ...but it brought error while debugging...plss hellppppppp

```
 public class play extends Activity {
TextView mTextField;
TextView score;
ToggleButton pause;
CountDownTimer countdown;
private long a;
private long b;
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.game);
    mTextField=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tme);
    score=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.score);
    score.setText("0" );
    final ImageButton menu=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.menu);
    menu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent=new Intent(play.this , GoodwordActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
   });

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    b= bundle.getInt("a");
    a=b;
    startCountDownTimer();
     pause=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.pause);
     pause.setText("");
     pause.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 if (pause.isChecked()) {
                     pause.setText("");
                     pause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.refresh);
                     countdown.cancel();

                       } else {
                           pause.setText("");
                           pause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);
                           startCountDownTimer();
                        }

            }
        });

}
 private void startCountDownTimer( )
 {
 countdown=new CountDownTimer(a, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished ) {

         a=millisUntilFinished;

         mTextField.setText("" + millisUntilFinished/1000);

         }
     public void onFinish() {
         a=b;

         startCountDownTimer();

     }
  }.start();
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to put the

```
mTextField.setText("0");
```

into the `onFinish()` function.

Comment: i got it!!  ntc posted it earlier..Dont knw why he removed it...That worked for me...simple logic...thanks for it @ntc.. 

     mTextField.setText("" + (millisUntilFinished-1000)/1000);